If $\{k_m\}^{\infty}_{m=1}$ is a collection of compact sets in $\Bbb R^n$, then $\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} k_m$ is a compact set.
Can you check my proof? Specifically the last part. Thanks.
If $\{k_m\}^{\infty}_{m=1}$ is a collection of compact sets in $\Bbb R^n$, then $\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} k_m$ is a compact set.
Let, $\pmb{g}=\{G_i\}^{\infty}_{i=1}$ an open cover of $\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} k_m$. And because $k_m$ are compact sets for all $m$, then there exists a finite subcover $G^m_i\subseteq \pmb g$ for each $k_m$, then we have that for all $m$, $k_m\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^{m} G^m_i$
Now, considering that and $\{G^m_i\}^{\infty}_{i=1}$, we have that $\bigcap^{\infty}_{m=1} k_m$ must be covered by $\bigcup^{m}_{i=1} G^m_i$
So, $\bigcup^{m}_{i=1} G^m_i\subseteq \pmb{g}=\{G_i\}^{\infty}_{i=1}$ and $\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} k_m$ is a compact set.

First, $\mathfrak g$ covers the meet of all $k_m$'s doesn't mean that it covers every $k_m$. Second, your last step just repeat that $\mathfrak g$ covers the meet of all $k_m$'s.

Other than what Zhang pointed out, showing that every countable cover has a finite subcover, is not enough. You should start with any arbitrary cover.

So if I take an arbitrary cover $\mathfrak{g}$ for $\bigcap_{m=1}^{\infty} k_m$, and then, we know that every $k_m$ is compact, so by def. each of them have a finite subcover $k_m\subseteq \mathfrak{g}^m_1, \forall m$, and if that covers the entire sets and we take ${\mathfrak{g}^m_i}^{\infty}{i=1}$, then it's valid to say $\bigcap{m=1}^{\infty} k_m\subseteq \bigcup^{\infty}_{i=1} \mathfrak{g}^m_1$. So we need to show that $\mathfrak{g}^m_1\subseteq \mathfrak{g}$, right?

Compact sets in $\mathbb R^n$ are closed and bounded. Since every $k_m$ is compact, the meet of all $k_m$'s, as a subset of every $k_m$, is bounded, and is closed, as the meet of some closed sets. Therefore, the meet of all $k_m$'s is closed and bounded and hence compact.
Actually, such proposition holds in all $T_2$ spaces. Recall that in a $T_2$ space, a compact subset is closed. The result follows from that a closed subset of a compact set is compact as well.
